# "Failed to execute goal on project" in Spring Boot Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I am traying to run spring boot application and I am getting error.Failed to execute goal on project.

I have tried

**1)maven --> update project**

**2)maven clean --> install**

**3)maven install**

But not worked after several steps

> Failed to execute goal on project [36mopenapi-generator-online[m:
> [1;31mCould not
> resolve dependencies for project org.openapitools:openapi-generator-online:jar:6.3.0-
> SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.openapitools:openapi-generator:jar:6.3.0-
> SNAPSHOT[m (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy-
> dependencies:default:package)

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-project</artifactId>
        <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
        <version>6.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
        <relativePath>../..</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-online</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>openapi-generator-online</name>
    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>2.7.5</spring-boot.version>
        <springfox-version>3.0.0</springfox-version>
        <sonar.exclusions>**/org/openapitools/codegen/online/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <finalName>openapi-generator-online</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>${project.parent.basedir}${file.separator}google_checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>static-analysis</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeFilterFile>${project.parent.basedir}${file.separator}spotbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>se.bjurr.violations</groupId>
                        <artifactId>violations-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Should be decreased regularly down to 0 as issues are fixed. -->
                            <maxViolations>3</maxViolations>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Validation API support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: There is no `6.3.0-SNAPSHOT` version of openapi in maven central. Remove the snapshot part. I don't really get why you set openapi as a parent project, that seems just wrong.

Comment: That looks strange to use the openapi as parent?